# Webpage source code displaying instead of content

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have written a website using HTML and CSS and, basically, I'm trying to get it to display now. The code is just a page of text and a few images. Currently when I go to the domain, the source code from start to finish is displayed instead of the actual content.

I just got cPanel hosting with godaddy (who naturally weren't of any help). I downloaded cyberduck. Uploaded the file containing the HTML text and called it index.html.

**A CSS file was uploaded, and saved as index.css** This might be the issue if something was incorrect.

On cyberduck it says there is a file called layout-style.css, perhaps I should edit that and add my CSS code to it?

Possibly the top few lines of the HTML code are missing some important command? [updated]:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<div class = enterprise> <br>
<p>text<p>
</div>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Also, does Bootstrap have to be installed anywhere?

I appreciate your responses.

Comment: Tags like `div`, `p` should be within `body` and not within `head` section.

Comment: And remove the ` at the start and the end maybe?

Bootstrap does not need to be present to have a html page. It will not act correct, but it should still display as a page

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen the ` is a typo just in StackOverflow.  @G-Akshay I'll tidy it up. there actually isn't a <body> tag I should get that in.

Comment: @EasyBB this is my first webpage lol. the div with the [.] is just cos the top line was displaying too close to the top of the screen ;-P

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen i want the page to look good on mobile. Bootstrap is installed on my mac. I'm not sure if it needs to be installed anywhere else.

Comment: Although any mistakes in your code, it should not render all html tags as code otherwise the file that you are using is not named with html extension correctly or your hosting server settings.

Comment: You will have to add at least the bootstrap css file and use the styles as indicated (see http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ for too many details). If you want some of the style effects, the JS file is also required.

Comment: Could you supply us with the URL at which this page is found?!

Comment: @sємsєм [link](http://econengines.com) . Norbert: not used any JS code. Thanks for the link! Will update the code re: bootstrap.

Comment: @Miramolin In your case, you have to contact the hosting technical support and asking them what is the default index for the public root? It is clear that it is a server issue that response as .html downloading it as .txt

Comment: @sємsєм godaddy were useless. the operative didn't know what css was when I called them up. do you mean that index.html might need to be saved as something else? how could I upload the CSS code?

Comment: As you said there is cPanel, Try open the file manager of the cPanel and note that to show all files, and search for a file named `.htaccess` then update your question with its contents. @Miramolin

Answer (score 2):

The content must be in the body tag
The structure of an HTML document is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Article</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
    <div >
      <h1>Site name</h1>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have  in the  part.
This is a html5 structure :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Then you should put  inside the  part like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class= top>

    </div>

    <div class = enterprise>
        <p> text goes here </p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```